# How to move root server application to some where else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting

I Have elastic search application up and running in ruby on rails.
Actual its on in the root path of the sever. Is it possible to move it to a subdirectory? What is necessary req. for it? what procedure i need to follow

Comment: What do you mean by a "root server"? Do you mean moving the app between subdirectories (as opposed to keeping in the `root` path?)

Comment: @RichPeck yes exactly

Comment: Okay let me edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: oh that would be a great!!

Comment: @RichPeck do you have any suggestion regarding this

Comment: Yep let me write it out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've never done this specifically, I believe it's very simple to do:

---

**Routes**

Your Rails app's routes are all relative, meaning they don't depend on having "domain.com" as the root path:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "controller#action"
```

The beauty of Rails is that since all your requests are handled through the [ActionDispatch::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) middleware, you'd basically need to ensure the routes work in order to get the whole application working

---

**Moving**

This means that if you're able to deploy your application successfully into a directory, you should be able to get it running regardless of where it is

I would do this:

> 1. [New Git Repo](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) in subdir
> 2. [Change `database.yml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304576/how-do-i-set-up-the-database-yml-file-in-rails) if db server is different
> 3. Redeploy app to new Git
> 4. Test to see if it works (load on new directory)