# rails app deployment on heroku - database does not update

Tags: ruby, git, repository

Hello I am trying to deploy my rails app from cloud9 via git to heroku. I am able to push all of my changes to git and then push the data to heroku with

```
git push heroku master
```

next I migrate my database to heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

However, when I visit the app on heroku, my data from the database does not show up. How can I fix this?

Comment: what command are you using to push?

Comment: I tried git push and git push master

Comment: git add -A 
git commit -m "text"
git push origin master

try this

Comment: okay now I created a new heroku app with "heroku create" and pushed my data via "git push heroku master". I also used "heroku run rake db:migrate". However, when I visit the app now, the data from the database is missing out...how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using 2 seperate databases. Migrate doesn't add the data. Just copy the database structure, but it's a new database.

Now you either re-create the data to the database on Heroku or you connect to your local database remotly though database.yml

Comment: Hello Boltz0r, thank you very much for your answer! Can you please tell me how to copy the database structure and how to re-create it? Or is there any link where to read how this works? I am fairly new to rails and git :S

Comment: there is no way to copy the data from one to the other... what you can do is connect to your local database. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304576/how-do-i-set-up-the-database-yml-file-in-rails