# How do I setup username and password on postgresql database.yml for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to start an application on ruby on rails with postgresql but I'm fairly new and unfamiliar with the process. I'm running into a password error when I try to launch the rail server on localhost:3000. Here is the error I'm getting.

fe_sendauth: no password supplied

```
    # connected server's characteristics.
    def connect
      @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters) <!-- This line says there's an issue -->
      configure_connection
    rescue ::PG::Error => error
      if error.message.include?("does not exist")
```

Anyone know how I can set up the username and password on windows or what I need to do to get around this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up the database.yml file in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304576/how-do-i-set-up-the-database-yml-file-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

*config/database.yml*

```
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres_password
  database: development_db

production: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres_password
  database: production_db
```