# User registration integration test is not inserting values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

I am new in rails testing and I have written an integration test for user signup. Test is working fine but it is not inserting record in the database.

Here is the code

```
require 'test_helper'

class SignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "user signup" do
    visit new_user_registration_path
    fill_in "user_email",    with: "abc@gmail.com"
    fill_in "user_password", with: "password"
    fill_in "user_password_confirmation", with: "password"
    click_button "Sign up"
    assert_text "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
  end
end
```

This is the command that I am using to run the test

```
rake test:integration
```

When I run the test the results are

```
Run options: --seed 62721

# Running:

.

Finished in 3.116669s, 0.3209 runs/s, 0.3209 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I have also checked the logs but nothing in the log.

This is my gemlist for testing

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Comment: How do you check that record was not inserted to the DB?

Comment: @mrzasa I have installed database client "dbeaver". No new record is showing in the database(test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test database is cleaned up after each test run so you will not be able to see any records after you run your test suite (depending on the cleaning method you won't be able to see anything in the DB even *during* the test if you use different connection to the DB).

If you want to test that user was saved, you need to do it inside the integration test. For example

```
# ...
assert_text "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
assert(User.where(email: "abc@gmail.com").exists?)
```

Or event better - write a unit test that checks it.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49210133/580346)

Comment: This is what I have got after inserting your code

Run options: --seed 25384

# Running:

.

Finished in 3.650668s, 0.2739 runs/s, 0.5478 assertions/s.
1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Is this correct result?

Comment: Can you please guide me that how to run a single test currently when I enter this command rails test:integration all the tests start running.

Comment: Yup, see that assertion number increased - that's the one for the user. You can also try to make the test fail (e.g. by commenting some parts of the production code. Regarding running a single test, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507074/580346)

Comment: no it is not working 
ruby -I test test/integration/signup_test.rb -n signup

result is 

Run options: -n signup --seed 46418

# Running:



Finished in 0.002650s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: it's rather  `ruby -I test test/integration/signup_test.rb -n "user signup"`

Comment: same results 0 0 0 0.